# Isomorphism of bipartite graphs

Tags: graph, bipartite, isomorphism

It is need to create a simple algorithm that determines the isomorphism of two bipartite graphs in any programming language.
I guess it's connect with matrix of two graphs but I dunno

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [GI-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem), so there is unlikely to be any efficient algorithm that works correctly on any algorithms (unless the graphs are quite small).  In practice, you can use a software package like nauty, bliss, etc.

Comment: Graph isomorphism restricted to bipartite graphs is not GI-hard. Indeed bipartite graphs are a subset of [permutation graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_graph) for which [GI is solved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#Solved_special_cases), an algorithm is given in  https://doi.org/10.1002/net.3230110103

Comment: @Diego, That doesn't sound right.  I don't believe bipartite graphs are a subset of permutation graphs.  For instance, the graph with V={1,2,3} and E={(1,2),(2,3)} is bipartite but is not a permutation graph.  Do you think I am missing something?

Comment: Ah! I was mistaken indeed, bipartite graphs are indeed GI-complete (even some of its subclasses are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#GI-complete_classes_of_graphs). Thanks @D.W. for pointing that out, I would have spent much more time until I figured this out :)